# Polymer 1.0: Refresh/Re-Render Computed Value Without Property Binding

Tags: polymer-1.0

I'm trying to re-compute and render a value within a `Polymer 1.0` template. However, I'm trying to do this without binding to any properties.

In case it matters, the use case is for a translation mechanism that uses a string key to find the translated value. When the 'translations' value changes, the `translate()` call needs to be re-computed.

The component definition is as follows :

```
<dom-module id="my-component">
    <template>
        <style></style>
        <p><span>[[translate("SOME_STRING")]]</span></p>
    </template>

    <script>
        var MyComponent = Polymer({
            is: "my-component",
            properties: {
                translations: {
                    type: Object,
                    notify: true,
                    value: {
                        "SOME_STRING": "Some String"
                    }
                }
            },
            translate: function (key) {
                if (this.translations.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    return this.translations[key];
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

I can get the refresh to work by adding the `translations` property to the `translate()` call as follows :

```
<p><span>[[translate("SOME_STRING", translations)]]</span></p>
```

However, what I would like to do is re-compute/refresh without having to put the `translations` property as a second parameter in every call (there's other reasons too).

Basically, when the `translations` object updates with different locale translations, I'd like the `translate("SOME_STRING")` to be re-computed.

Is this possible? Is there any way to re-render the template or even just re-render the entire component manually? How? If not, what is the simplest way to get the computed value or template re-rendered without a property in the binding?

Comment: I do something like this with dom-if. I have an 'initialized' property set to false and when the translation finished loading, I set it to true which gets the part in the dom-if template rendered, thereby evaluting the computed values. Although I'm at Polymer 3 today, I see that even Polymer 1 already supported it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How about that????**

```
<dom-module id="my-component">
<template>
    <style></style>
    <p><span>[[str]]</span></p>
</template>

<script>
    var MyComponent = Polymer({
        is: "my-component",
        properties: {
            translations: {
                type: Object,
                notify: true,
                value: {
                    "SOME_STRING": "Some String"
                },
                observer: '_Changed'
            },
            str: {
                type: String,
                value: "hello"
              }

        },
        _Changed: function(){
           this.set("str",this.translate(this.str));
        },
        translate: function (key) {
            if (this.translations.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                return this.translations[key];
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Dam!

Comment: Dam, I get what you're trying to say... but this is still using a property within the template. Your example has given me some ideas, thanks! However, I'll need to see if this approach will work. It's not what I was hoping for but this might be the best answer. Let me play with it and I'll let you know.

Comment: You want to support multiple language in your web??

Comment: Yeah... over 1000 translations. I'd prefer to keep the definitions dynamic instead of creating a property for each one.

Comment: Dam, instead of this, I could just `<p><span>[[translations.SOME_STRING]]</span></p>`. However, I still need it to be a computed value since there are arguments that need to be passed. For example, `<p><span>[[translate("SOME_STRING", arg1, arg2)]]</span></p>`. So far, it looks like the only way to refresh the computation is to include a property that updates when the active locale changes... `<p><span>[[translate("SOME_STRING", activeLocale, arg1, arg2)]]</span></p>`.

Comment: I have a another way.
You can put all words to file javascript like that:
en.js --> for English
vi.js --> for Vietnamese 
...
u just add script like that:
<script src="scripts/lang/en.js"></script>
You store languge in cookies 
When you load language (ex: vi )in cookies you put
<script src="scripts/lang/vi.js"></script> to your project

Format file language
var i18n = {
  cannot_launch_action: "Can not launch this action",
  cancel: "Cancel",
  cofirm_invalid: "Invalid confirmed password",
...
}

Comment: Thanks Dam... I'm already loading the locale translations that way. It's now a matter of getting the translations (re)computed when needed with Polymer.